# How to save new account in ganache-cli

Tags: accounts, web3.py, ganache, cli

[image: my ganache -cli environment]

I use `ganache-cli --db` to create a private test chain and save it on my computer,
and the result is below:
[image]

I use web3py `w3.personal.newAccount('1')` to add a new address, and I use `print(len(w3.personal.listAccounts))` to show the amount of accounts, and the result is below[image]

but when I shut down(ctrl +c) and turn on the  ganache-cli again, I find there is no account saved.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify a location to save and load the DB from.

Both times you run the command, simply specify a location, like so:

`ganche-cli --db="~/my/DB/path"`

Comment: I try add my location but no helps. Could you please give me some more details?